# Typing in zeta function using maxima

Tags: maxima-software

How do I type the symbols in for this formula into maxima (it's the zeta function)?  I'm looking for the proper symbols/keys/text sequence.  Example in latex to get the **zeta symbol** you type in **\zeta** but what sequence of letters and symbols does one type in to get the formula below.

[image]

Comment: **bfzeta (s, n)** returns the Riemann zeta function for the argument s. The return value is a big float (bfloat); n is the number of digits in the return value.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici thanks but I was looking for how to type in the equation.  Example in latex typing in the zeta symbol is \zeta but I'm not sure how to type the full equation above in maxima

Comment: I suppose it is just $zeta(s)$. Do you want to write the formula for the rhs ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici thanks that's the first symbol is there list telling you how to type in the rest of the symbols?  I haven't been able to locate a list on google.

Comment: lsum (x^i, i, [1, 2, 7]);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply zeta(s). "If [s] is a negative integer, 0, or a positive even integer, the Riemann zeta function simplifies to an exact value. For a positive even integer the option variable zeta%pi has to be true in addition (See zeta%pi)".  See http://maxima.sourceforge.net/docs/manual/en/maxima_29.html.